# I need to split a number into separate digits in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a number in my XML, e.g. 12345678. I need to split this number into digits and multiply it with e.g. 87654321, like this:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
4  3  5  6  7  8  2  1
----------------------
4  6 15 24 35 48 14  9
```

Is there any way I can do it using XSLT?

Comment: Please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="input">
        <xsl:variable name="sort">
       <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[0-9]">
           <xsl:matching-substring>
               <i><xsl:value-of select="."/></i>
           </xsl:matching-substring>
           <xsl:non-matching-substring>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
           </xsl:non-matching-substring>
       </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$sort/i">
            <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>    

        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
You may also use this to sort your number.
```

Change order according to your need ascending or decending

Answer (score 0):

If your processor supports XSLT 2.0, you could do something like this:

**XML**

```
<input>43567821</input>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="factors">12345678</xsl:param> 

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="for $i in 1 to string-length(input) return number(substring(input, $i, 1)) * number(substring($factors, $i, 1))"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>4 6 15 24 35 48 14 8</output>
```

Note that this requires that the number of digits in `factors` is equal to or greater than the number of digits in the input.